# Non-autonomous System of First-Order ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:

> $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} - tx = 0$

I understand that the solutions to this ODE are the Airy and Bairy functions, but I'm unsure how to find solutions to the following approach. Considering $y = \frac{dx}{dt}$, we get the following system:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dt} &= tx\\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= y
\end{align*}

This is obviously non-autonomous, no matter what I do (including googling), I can't seem to find a way to solve this system. I figured maybe plugging values such as $y(t_0) = x'(t_0) = x'_0$ and $y'(t_0) = y'_0$ and using numerical methods to try to find behaviours in outcomes, but it fails to look like the Airy/Bairy function (or I did it incorrectly). How can I solve this system algebraically?

Comment: $x(t) = \alpha {\rm Ai}(t) + \beta {\rm Bi}(t) $ is the solution to the problem, I don't think you can solve this algebraically. Do you want to find an algebraic expression for ${\rm Ai}(t)$?

Comment: Well, of course that's the solution to the equations, but I was wondering if there was a different way to find patterns in behaviors to solutions similar to how autonomous systems are solved. I've decided setting a range for $t$ and finding a general solution when $t>0$ and $t<0$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: you want to find some properties of the solutions, without using the fact that the solution is an Airy function. Is that right?

Comment: Correct, sorry if that wasn't very clear

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand the first time. You can try taking the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of the original equation, this will change your problem to a First order ODE which you can algebraically solve. From this, you can gain some intuition of the shape of the function